# Stop cmd if the batch job returns warning on execution

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have created different batch files to make backup of different folders and I created another batch file to execute these batch files all at once. Upon execution of each batch job its cmd window closes. On occasion, if a certain file from the folder being backed up is in use, I get warning message in cmd window but the execution doesn't stop. How can I make this batch job stop upon this kind of warning?

I have tried different lines but I didn't do anything, I suppose it's because this isn't an error but rather a warning.
This is what I get: `WARNING: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

```
start cmd /c call JZU20-backup.bat exit /b%ERRORLEVEL%

start cmd /c call JZU20-backup.bat if errorlevel 1 exit /B 1

start cmd /c call JZU20-backup.bat if errorlevel 1 eof
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't state whether your backups can be individually identified, so...

```
:makeflagfile
set "flagfilename=%temp%\%random%.flg"
if exist "%flagfilename%" (goto makeflagfile) else (echo.>"%flagfilename%")
.... your backup mainline ....

:retry
yourbackupstepthatgeneratestheerrormessage>>"%flagfilename%"
find "cannot access" "%flagfilename%" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 timeout /t 300 >nul&echo.>"%flagfilename%"&goto retry
del "%flagfilename%"
```

This should generate a file with a random name (which identifies this *particular* instance of the backup job), then extend that file with the report from the failing step.

If the report contains "cannot access" then delay for 300 seconds, clear the file and try again. Otherwise, delete the file.

{untried}